# It is impossible to catch scroll event in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to catch scrolling event of list component in ionic3 as in this example:

```html
<ion-content on-scroll = "scrolling()" on-scroll-complete = "scrollComplete()">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
              item="item"
              href="#/item/{{item.id}}">
      Item {{ item.id }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>   
</ion-content>
```

https://codepen.io/etipirev/pen/aNYNpy?editors=1111

as it is seemed it is working in ionic 1, but not in ionic 3? i havent found any event description in ionic docs. is it possible to catch scrolling of list items in ionic 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is different in Ionic2/3. Here's how it should be:

```
<ion-content (ionScroll)="scrolling($event)" (ionScrollEnd)="scrollComplete($event)">
  <ion-list>
   ...
  </ion-list>   
</ion-content>
```

then in your ts file

```
constructor(){}
  scrolling(event) {
    // your content here for scrolling
  }

  scrollComplete(event) {
    // your content here of scroll is finished
  }
}
```